# Swift: Variadic in @objc_block for function in JSContext

Tags: swift, javascriptcore

I'm using JavaScriptCore in Swift, and want to set a javascript function to a swift objc_block.

This works great without a variadic:

```
var log : @objc_block (String, String, String) -> Void = { string1, string2, string3 in
   println("log:\(string1), \(string2), \(string3)")
 }
context.objectForKeyedSubscript("console").setObject(unsafeBitCast(log, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "log");
// invoking console.log("arg1", "arg2", "arg3") will print log:arg1, arg2, arg3
```

But with a variadic I get an error:

```
var log : @objc_block (String...) -> Void = { string in
  // do some logging
}
```

The error, thrown in JavaScript and caught with `context.exceptionHandler` , is:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert primitive to NSArray
```

Which makes sense if it's trying to convert the arguments in javascript (primitives) to the the array I'm expecting in the swift block. Either there's some magic that's not happening in the JSContext, or I'm doing it wrong (I've only been using swift for a few hours).

The complete code is:

```
let context = JSContext()
context.evaluateScript("var window = this; var console = {};")
context.exceptionHandler = { context, exception in
  println("JS Error: \(exception)")
}
var log : @objc_block (String...) -> Void = { string in
  // do some logging
}
context.objectForKeyedSubscript("console").setObject(unsafeBitCast(log, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "log");
```

Comment: I was looking how to get Javascript callbacks to Swift code and found this your hack in your question with @objc_block and unsafeBitCast(..., AnyObject.self) cast. Started working for me only after I applied them both. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should declare your function in ObjC/Swift as following:

```
JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
context[@"func"] = ^void() {
    NSArray *arguments = [JSContext currentArguments];
    ...
};
[context evaluateScript:@"func(2, 3, 4, 1)"];
```

Comment: This is correct. You can use `JSContext.currentArguments()` in Swift.